# Extracting area from DEM Raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, vector, dem

- After applying constraints to the DEM I polygonised the raster (using GRASS r.to.vect.area)
- The result is shown below with a lot of vector with resolution = [30 * 30]
- Is there any solution to make fusion if the difference DN between entities is 10 m for example?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imported my raster file to PostGIS and I used [this function](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_DumpAsPolygons.html) to make vectorization of my raster.

I used this query

> SELECT (ST_DumpAsPolygons(rast)).geom,(ST_DumpAsPolygons(rast)).val from my_raster